# mvc3 - adding CSS class based on model attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got a model element like so:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First name")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and I'm using an EditorFor to pump it out to the page like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName )
```

I have many of these elements on a page and would like to add a CSS class to the input field called 'Required' based on whether or not the model has a [Required] attribute.

Adding...

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "Required" }) )
```

...seems a bit manual.  Is there a way I can do this dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you don't need to support the oldest browsers, you could also use the `data-val-required` html attribute which is already automatically added to the fields. In CSS this would be for example `input[type="text"][data-val-required] { border-left: 2px solid blue; }`.

Comment: That'll do for me.  Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 6):

> seems a bit manual.

and most importantly not working. The second argument of the `EditorFor` helper doesn't do what you think it does, contrary to the `TextBoxFor` helper. You could write a [custom metadata provider](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) which would allow you to decorate our view model property  with a custom attribute and specify the class to apply on the editor template:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First name")]
[StringLength(50)]
[HtmlProperties(CssClass = "Required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest overriding creating an EditorTemplate: /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml

Put this in the contents (sorry untested!):

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line" + (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired ? " required" : "") })
```