# ASP.NET MVC 5 and HTML 5 form attributes according to the W3C specs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

As for as I know it seems like Microsoft are using jQuery validation attributes as default for form input attributes.

Is it possible to configure my application so if I add the `Required` attribute and render my form using `@Html.EditorFor(x => Model)` the form will be rendered using `required` attributes instead of `data-val-required`? Or am I forced to write my own `EditorTemplates` for all standard types?

Comment: Not the same but below SO question, the form will render "Required" using Html attribute. Fairly manual approach though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788231/mvc3-adding-css-class-based-on-model-attributes

Comment: you can off jquery validation for elements you want and then supply html5 attributes thr.  notice data- attributes are part of HTML5..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to replace the standard `data-*` validation attributes used by ASP.NET MVC you should start by disabling unobtrusive client side validation in your web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
```

This will prevent the html helpers from emitting them on your input fields.

Then you could write custom editor templates for the standard types. For example for string that would be `~/Views/Shared/editorTemplates/String.cshtml`:

```
@{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    attributes["class"] = "text-box single-line";
    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
    {
        attributes["required"] = "required";
    }
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, attributes)
```

And that's pretty much it. Now everytime you do an `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)` where `Foo` is a string property it will generate the following markup:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Foo" name="Foo" required="required" type="text" value="" />
```

It's also worth mentioning that if you don't want to disable unobtrusive client side validation and the `data-*` attributes for your entire application but only for a single form you could do that:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    this.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
}
```

Comment: @darindimitrov Sir, can you give me advice, what could be the reason that html5 constraint form validation is not working in my mvc 5 web site. Well, actually it kind of working but there is no warning message showing. I have been looking for the solution for three days :(